# Automatic cloning and iscsi sharing of zfs dataset on connect

Tags: systemd, zfs

Since iSCSI was not designed to support multiple concurrent clients accessing the same dataset, is it technically possible without modifying code/recompiling (but maybe create scripts and systemd sockets?) to snapshot and clone a dataset for each client, presenting it to the requesting client, and destroy it when the client disconnect?

The data would be lost at disconnect unless the main version of the dataset was mounted which would be okay as it is intended to be used as read-only.